# Header naming convention

Tags: c, header-files

From

[How can I define a C function in one file, then call it from another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4271717)

> Say I define a function in the file `func1.c`, and I want to call it from
>   the file `call.c`, how would I accomplish this?

and the answer

> You would put a declaration for the function in the file `func1.h`, and add
>   `#include "func1.h"` in `call.c`.  Then you would compile or link `func1.c`
>   and `call.c` together (details depend on which C system).

My question is does the name of the header file **have to be** `func1.h`, as in `<name-of-c-file>.h`, or is this just a best practice? Please provide link for reference if possible.

Answer (score 5):

In `c`, you don't have to call your files anything at all. As such, you can call your header  `mylongheadername.h`, while you call your source file `a.c` and have a function in it called `justArandomFunctionName`.

However, you should be aware that your source file needs to include your header file. Generally there is a strong link between headers and source files, so that's the reason this is just about always done in this way. However, the following is completely valid:

```
a.c : func1 implementation
      func2 implementation

b.c : func3 implementation
      func4 implementation

c.h : func1 declaration
      func3 declaration

d.h : func2 declaration
      func4 declaration
```

However,  there are some problems to this approach that might occur when using files set up like this (which mean you have to put extra work into structuring these files right) and it's just poor practice. But, the way one uses header files is just convention and barely any of it is enforced by the language.

---

Then there is the question how this can work if the header file does not know where the function is defined. The idea of this is that it doesn't need to know.

Basically, all your header does is tell your compiler that somewhere you defined a function that fits a certain profile (what name, what parameters, what return type). When your compiler reads this, basically all it does is mix all this info into a fancy name, which it will then insert into the file that is calling, which means it still doesn't do anything. The next step you need to take is to use the linker to turn the compiled versions of each of your files into a single executable. This does a number of things, but one of the most important ones is that it resolves all those fancy names the compiler cooked up. However, the way that your linker does this, is that it just reads all the compiled versions of your files and matches the definition of functions to their actual location in other code. Because it just handles all you have at the same time, it doesn't matter where your functions were defined and the header file never needs to know this.

Comment: @Jasper, I think it better to use `a.h` to instead of `c.h`, use `b.h` to instead of `d.h`, so that, gcc and make can easy implement.

Comment: @HowChen: it is most definitely better, I agree with that completely. However, this better demonstrates my point that you can do just about anything.

Comment: @Jasper: I was just kidding about the badge.  Since it was edited, the question popped up as "Recent," so I was getting ready to +1 anyway then saw the dates.  After I commented, I actually checked to see if you had it and hoped you realized I was joking.  Well, there's still an Archaeologist badge out there! ;)

Comment: @StevenPenny It's a little hard to find a "reference link". That's because the answer to the question is basically "no, there are no rules". References tend to describes rules, rather than rulelessness. On top of that, there are *conventions*, which mean that people tend to want to put as little emphasis on the rulelessness as possible, since you aren't really expected to use it. However, conventions are non-authoritative by definition, so a reference to a convention doesn't really do much either... I'll see what I can find, though

Answer (score 2):

No, header files do not need to match any corresponding C source file.  It is as you've said just convention.

Comment: Hi Steve, I'm not aware of a reference link -- the #include directive is in a sense a stand-alone feature of the pre-processor.  It can be used to pull in _anything_ including raw C code.  The statement is replaced by the contents of the file that's mentioned.  So afaik it is convention and not necessarily a standard (even the locations of header files isn't part of a standard).  HTH